# Pointer is not being written properly

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have this code right here. I was wondering why parseCommand does not write to "queues" in the main function. Am I doing something wrong? I am suppose to have 3 different types of queues and parseCommand returns a command in the format of "enqueue,1,Class-section,name", and it's supposed to be storing in in a linked list depending on what queue number it's supposed to be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hw08-header.h"    /*  note header  */

typedef struct node{
    int classNumber;
    char *className;
    struct node *next;
} Queue;

void parseCommand(char *cmd, Queue **queue);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char *value = "go";
    int key;
    Queue *queues = calloc(3, sizeof(Queue));

    (queues)->next = NULL;
    (queues + (sizeof(Queue) * 1))->next = NULL;
    (queues + (sizeof(Queue) * 2))->next = NULL;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("  usage:  program_name positive_integer\n");
        printf("example:  ./example-hw08  123\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /**************  begin REQUIRED  **************/
    /*  put before logic.  DO NOT PUT IN A LOOP */
    key = atoi(argv[1]);
    initialize(key);
    /**************   end REQUIRED   **************/

    while(strcmp(value, "stop") != 0)
    {
        value = getString();
        parseCommand(value, &queues);
    }

    printf("%d\n", (queues + 1)->classNumber);
}

void parseCommand(char *cmd, Queue **queue) {
  char *verb, *class, *name, *className;
  int queueNumber, classNumber;
  Queue *tempQueue = *queue, *node, *p;

  verb = strtok(cmd, ",");

  if(strcmp(verb, "stop") != 0) {
    if(strcmp(verb, "enqueue") == 0) {
      queueNumber = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
      class = strtok(NULL, ",");
      name = strtok(NULL, ",");
      className = strtok(class, " ");
      classNumber = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));

      printf("%s enters line %d to register for %s %d\n", name, queueNumber, className, classNumber);

      node = malloc(sizeof(queue));

      node->classNumber = classNumber;
      node->next = NULL;

      p = tempQueue;

      while(p->next != NULL) {
        p = p->next;
      }

      p->next = node;
      p = node;

      *queue = tempQueue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) `(queues + (sizeof(Queue) * 1))->next = NULL;` --> `(queues + 1)->next = NULL;` or `queues[1].next = NULL;` 2) `node = malloc(sizeof(queue));` --> `node = malloc(sizeof(Queue));`

Comment: No, it's writing it in the main function. However parseCommand does not write to the pointer specified in the second parameter of the function.

Comment: I apologize if I don't understand, but what exactly do you mean by (queues + 1) is zombie? The intent of the code is to parse the command, then enqueue the corresponding data onto the linked list specified. The error here is that the function parseCommand does not properly write to the queues variable in the main function.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand. I deleted comment (3)

Comment: Okay, however the solution in (1) does not work unfortunately. The pointer isn't being changed by parseCommand.

Comment: `queues + (sizeof(Queue) * 1)` : Address after pointer arithmetic is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for that, I changed it, however that's not the are that I am worried about. I am confused about how `*queue = tempQueue;` does not work.

Comment: you want `printf("%d\n", queues->next->classNumber;` instead of `printf("%d\n", (queues + 1)->classNumber);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108060/discussion-between-kngu-and-bluepixy).